# Mac Java 7 Crash while getting a tooltip after toggling to 'mirror display' on Mac

Tags: macos, java-7

There is a consistently reproducible crash when toggling 'mirror display' on while a Swing application is running on a dual monitor machine, then immediately overing over something that has a tooltip.

I only see this on OS X 10.8. I could not reproduce it on 10.7.

1. Compile and run the sample code against Java 7 on a Mac with OS X 10.8 (with dual monitor) in a 'display mirroring' off state.
2. Hover over the JLabel to see a tooltip
3. Toggle display mirroring on.
4. Hover over the JLabel again and you should get a crash.

   ```
   public class TestToolTip {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           JFrame frame = new JFrame();

           JLabel label = new JLabel("hover");

           label.setToolTipText("tooltip text");
           frame.add(label);
           frame.setVisible(true);
           frame.pack();
       }
   }
   ```

I've also seen this when closing a laptop on a running application instead of the 'mirror on' step.

```
PlugIn Path:       /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/lwawt/liblwawt.dylib
PlugIn Identifier: liblwawt.dylib
PlugIn Version:    ??? (1)

Date/Time:       2013-07-04 12:09:43.467 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.2 (12C60)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          6164497 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           67
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  23880 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   2

Crashed Thread:  0  AppKit Thread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** CFRelease() called with NULL ***

Thread 0 Crashed:: AppKit Thread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8513e7d8 CFRelease + 40
1   liblwawt.dylib                  0x0000000168eae647 __Java_sun_lwawt_macosx_CWrapper_00024NSObject_release_block_invoke_1 + 91
2   JavaNativeFoundation            0x00000001682d55f5 +[JNFRunLoop _performCopiedBlock:] + 20
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff88d31677 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 225
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff85148101 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff85147a25 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 245
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8516adc5 __CFRunLoopRun + 789
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8516a6b2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
8   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff901410a4 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 209
9   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff90140e42 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 356
10  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff90140cd3 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8dc19613 _DPSNextEvent + 685
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8dc18ed2 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128
13  libosxapp.dylib                 0x0000000168f2fb56 -[NSApplicationAWT nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 124
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8dc10283 -[NSApplication run] + 517
15  libosxapp.dylib                 0x0000000168f2f9b9 +[NSApplicationAWT runAWTLoopWithApp:] + 156
16  liblwawt.dylib                  0x0000000168e8981a -[AWTStarter starter:] + 1591
17  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff88d31677 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 225
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff85148101 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
19  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff85147a25 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 245
20  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8516adc5 __CFRunLoopRun + 789
21  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8516a6b2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
22  java                            0x0000000102a8842d CreateExecutionEnvironment + 871
23  java                            0x0000000102a82bdc JLI_Launch + 1952
24  java                            0x0000000102a8878a main + 101
25  java                            0x0000000102a82434 start + 52

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8bf70386 __semwait_signal + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff884eacbd pthread_join + 847
2   java                            0x0000000102a87a2d ContinueInNewThread0 + 102
3   java                            0x0000000102a83847 ContinueInNewThread + 201
4   java                            0x0000000102a87790 JVMInit + 251
5   java                            0x0000000102a835c5 JLI_Launch + 4489
6   java                            0x0000000102a8878a main + 101
7   java                            0x0000000102a880bf apple_main + 92
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff88460742 _pthread_start + 327
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8844d181 thread_start + 13

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8bf700fa __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff88464f89 _pthread_cond_wait + 869
2   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000102f5c547 os::PlatformEvent::park() + 173
3   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000102f3f7bc ParkCommon(ParkEvent*, long long) + 42
4   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000102f3ffae Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long long) + 160
5   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000102f4018a Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) + 246
6   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000103023168 Threads::destroy_vm() + 80
7   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000102e4e2ba jni_DestroyJavaVM + 223
8   java                            0x0000000102a83b86 JavaMain + 805
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff88460742 _pthread_start + 327
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8844d181 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8bf70d16 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff84e84dea _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 883
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff84e849ee _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8bf700fa __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff88464f89 _pthread_cond_wait + 869
2   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000102f5c547 os::PlatformEvent::park() + 173
3   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000102f3f7bc ParkCommon(ParkEvent*, long long) + 42
4   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000102f3ffae Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long long) + 160
5   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000102f4020b Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) + 375
6   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000102dcd516 GCTaskManager::get_task(unsigned int) + 56
7   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000102dce34e GCTaskThread::run() + 338
8   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000102f601b5 java_start(Thread*) + 173
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff88460742 _pthread_start + 327
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8844d181 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8bf700fa __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff88464f89 _pthread_cond_wait + 869
2   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000102f5c547 os::PlatformEvent::park() + 173
3   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000102f3f7bc ParkCommon(ParkEvent*, long long) + 42
4   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000102f3ffae Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long long) + 160
5   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000102f4020b Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) + 375
6   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000102dcd516 GCTaskManager::get_task(unsigned int) + 56
7   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000102dce34e GCTaskThread::run() + 338
8   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000102f601b5 java_start(Thread*) + 173
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff88460742 _pthread_start + 327
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8844d181 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8bf700fa __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff88464f89 _pthread_cond_wait + 869
2   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000102f5d6b3 os::PlatformEvent::park(long long) + 385
3   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000102f3ffae Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long long) + 160
4   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000102f4020b Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) + 375
5   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000103053f2c VMThread::loop() + 444
```

Comment: I keep seeing this issue on one macbook, did you manage to solve this issue?